# What is the correct url to request the 404 page?

Tags: urls, 404-error, routing

I'd like to access the 404 page generated by wordpress through actually requesting it. It will need to be requested programmatically and I want to be sure it will always be the 404 content, so any random url to trigger an actual 404 wouldn't work. To make things right, it should also probably answer with the 200 http status.

[A documentation page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page#Help_Your_Server_Find_the_404_Page) says it should be `/index.php?error=404` but on my setup it only displays the homepage.

Has this been changed since the writing of the documentation or is it a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this this doesn't work when you have custom permalinks enabled. See the red warning box on the page you linked:

> WARNING: If you are using custom permalink, the trick below does not work, see this: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7592.

The trac ticket was closed as invalid so doesn't look like this will change.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed read too fast and didn't followed the warning. So, with the permalinks, there is no current way to actually request the 404 page ?

Comment: I don't know this code well sorry but I'd guess nothing has changed since the discussion on the trac ticket. It does seem silly there's no way to programmatically trigger it though, and ?error=404 looks a good way to me.

Comment: It looks like the `/404/` permalink is reserved as I tried to create it from a page and it automatically fellback to `/404-2/`. I'm having trouble to confirm it from the documentation though.